# Is it possible to change the type of several Cells at once in Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm learning Excel and I want to change all the checkboxes for YES with green background if they are true, and for NO with red background if it´s false. Does exist a way to do it not by hand? I hope so.

I tryed to use macros but didn´t work properly, maybe because I didn´t use them in the right way.

Thanks in advance :)

My table looks like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afgGZ.png)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming userform controls, you can link each of your checkboxes to their respective cell they reside in. If done, then use a conditional formatting rule (or two in this case):

[image]

Conditional formatting rule for `=$B$2:$C$2`:

[image]

Note that I formatted both the fill as the color of the text to be the same.